# how to fix forms password validation, password didn't match

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When i finished enter my username and password, this error is blow up, he write that username and password didn't match, but all data is valide and true! how to fix it?
How to check the password, if the password in the database is stored in encrypted form, and the supplied password in the form of a string!

Thank you all for your help, I will look forward to your advice!

forms.py

```
class UserLogInForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)), label=_("Username"), error_messages={ 'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.") })
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Password"))

def clean_username(self):
    user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    if user: 
        return self.cleaned_data['username']
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist!')

def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if user.count() == 1:
        user = user.first()
        if user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password!")
        return self.cleaned_data
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist!')
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    form = UserLogInForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
        password = form.cleaned_data['password'],

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
           return redirect('accounts/login')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration/login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are raising the error when the `check_password()` returns True.

I suggest you may re-write the method something like this,

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    try:            
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist!")  
    if user and not user.check_password(password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password!"):
    if user and not user.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active.")
    return super(UserLogInForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, remove the trailing commas from these lines in your view,

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
```

Due to the trailing commas, python returns a tuple rather than a string.

Comment: i can accept your answer only after 6 minutes, but i have 1 question, everything going good, but didn't authorize me

Comment: May I suggest a major change in your clean method??

Comment: It's better than I had, but such a question remained, he still does not authorize me, can you help me? To regret, I can create a question only every 90 minutes! (

Comment: Remove the trailing comma from the `username` and `password` lines in your view.

Comment: My God, with me the whole day is such a stupid little things I do not notice, thank you very much)

Comment: Welcome, no problem, happens to everyone. Glad I could be of some help.